# M2: issue after change to other template

Tags: magento2

after change M2 to other template I get below issue. (I clear old modules and theme files) I try deploy, compile etc. But still the same.

1

```
exception(s):
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Codazon\ThemeLayoutPro\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image does not exist
Exception #0 (ReflectionException): Class Codazon\ThemeLayoutPro\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image does not exist<pre>#1 Magento\Framework\Code\Reader\ClassReader->getConstructor() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Definition/Runtime.php:54]
#2 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Definition\Runtime->getParameters() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:48]
#3 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]
#4 Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->create() called at [vendor/magento/framework/Validator/UniversalFactory.php:36]
#5 Magento\Framework\Validator\UniversalFactory->create() called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/Entity/Attribute/AbstractAttribute.php:596]
#6 Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\AbstractAttribute->getBackend() called at [generated/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Eav/Attribute/Interceptor.php:806]
#7 Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute\Interceptor->getBackend() called at [vendor/magento/module-eav/Model/ResourceModel/ReadHandler.php:142]
#8 Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\ReadHandler->execute() called at [vendor/magento/framework/EntityManager/Operation/Read/ReadAttributes.php:59]
#9
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485331/class-magento-catalog-modelcategory-attribute-backend-layoutupdate-doesnot-exis... then check 'eav_attribute' table for that class

Comment: Resolved. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Your previous theme created custom eav_attributes.

Check your eav_attribute table for all references to Codazon\ThemeLayoutPro\Model\Category\Attribute\Backend\Image and delete them.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60485331/class-magento-catalog-modelcategory-attribute-backend-layoutupdate-doesnot-exis